# Test Class in Salesforce for a Trigger

Tags: salesforce, apex

Good day Everybody,

I am attempting to write a test class for a trigger I helped write.  The trigger uses a field called trigger_help__c, a formula field derived from adding the opportunity Type and Account ID, and fires before insert if an Opportunity of that type has been created on that account within the last 90 days.  Unless the profile is a system admin.  Here is my trigger:

```html
trigger leadDuplicatePreventer on opportunity(before insert) {
   set<string> settgs = new set<string>();
   list<opportunity> opps = [select id,Trigger_Help__c  from opportunity WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:90];
   Profile p=[SELECT ID, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() Limit 1];
   for(opportunity opp : opps){
     if(opp.Trigger_Help__c != null && p.Name <> 'System Administrator'){
  settgs.add(opp.Trigger_Help__c);
  }
   }
   
   for(opportunity op : trigger.new){
      if(settgs.contains(op.Trigger_Help__c)){
      op.adderror('An Opportunity of this type already exists on this Account.  Please contact a system administrator with questions.');
   }
   
   }


   
}​
```

I am having trouble writing the test class and I am clueless as always.  I have the following written, but I am lost as to what I actually need to be doing:

```html
@isTest
private class TestleadDuplicatePreventer {
    @isTest static void TestleadDuplicatePreventerwithOneOpp() {
        Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acct;
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name=acct.Name + ' Opportunity',
                                         StageName='Open Opportunity',
                                         CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                         Facility__c='Tacoma WA',
                                         Oppty_Type__c='UCO Service',
                                         AccountID=acct.Id);
        insert opp;
        Test.startTest();
        opp= new Opportunity(Name='Opportunity Test',
                            StageName='Open Opportunity',
                            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(2),
                            Facility__c='Tacoma WA',
                            Oppty_Type__c='UCO Service',
                            Account=[SELECT ID from Account WHERE Account.Name='Test Account']);
        try
        {
            insert opp;
        }
        catch(Exception duplicate)
        {       
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}​
```

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your requirements were for your project, you can probably get this done without code doing a rollup sum field that counts the opportunities tied to an account that has the type used in **Trigger_Help__c** and then put a validation on opportunity that when **ISNEW()** if **Account.Count_Of_Type__c > 0** causes the validation to fire OR on opportunity create a hidden field that is unique that is the concatenation of the account id and the Opportunity type which can be set by workflow or the process builder.  Tis would prevent duplicate types from being added for a given account.

But to your original question:  In your test I dont see you set the **Trigger_Help__c** field unless that is set by automation. Also when creating your second opp you dont need to do the query of account you can just  use the **acct.Id** from earlier in the code.

For your catch you need to assert that the e.getMessage() is the message you expect from your add error in the trigger.

You probably also need to do a separate where you runAs(admin_user) where admin_user is a user that you create with the System administrator profile to ensure that you dont get an error when you run as the admin user, along the lines of:

```
@isTest
private class TestleadDuplicatePreventer {
    @isTest static void TestleadDuplicatePreventerwithOneOpp() {
    Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert acct;
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name=acct.Name + ' Opportunity',
                                     StageName='Open Opportunity',
                                     CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                     Facility__c='Tacoma WA',
                                     Oppty_Type__c='UCO Service',
                                     AccountID=acct.Id);
    insert opp;
    Test.startTest();
    opp= new Opportunity(Name='Opportunity Test',
                        StageName='Open Opportunity',
                        CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(2),
                        Facility__c='Tacoma WA',
                        Oppty_Type__c='UCO Service',
                        AccountId=acct.Id);
    try
    {
        insert opp;
    }
    catch(Exception duplicate)
    {       
       System.assertEquals('An Opportunity of this type already exists on this Account.  Please contact a system administrator with questions.', duplicate.getMessage())
    }
    //this should probably be in a separate test method
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
  User u2 = new User(Alias = 'newUser', Email='newuser@testorg.com',
     EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
     LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
     TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='newuser@testorg.com');

  System.runAs(u2) {
      insert opp;
  }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

}​

Comment: Thank you!  The Trigger_Help__c is a formula field (the code says this field is not writable), should I still be inputting a value?  I am still not getting any code coverage.

Comment: You cannot write to  formula field.  Where are you checking for code coverage?  Try running the test from the Developer Console and checking the trigger coverage there.  You wont get test coverage for the test class, it would be for the item you are testing, so in this case it would be for the trigger.  Even your first test would have produces coverage for inserting an opportunity.

Comment: Thank you!  I eventually managed to get it.  You were right, the problem was in the need to test as multiple users and then I got the code coverage.  Then my other problem was fixed by changing the version settings of the class to match my production org.  Thank you for the help!!